# How to implement auth by credential in soapclient?

Tags: authentication, servicestack, webservice-client

I found the method " WcfServiceClient.SetCredential" is commented, so I try create new ChannelFactory and assign the property "Credentials.UserName" with my username & password, but it return httpcode 403 always. any body who can tell me why?

Thanks
Gary